Show about three humans that piloted three giant machines, each with different abilities
I'm trying to find a show I watched in Canada in the 90s when I was a kid. It could have been a little older, so 80s-90s.
The show was about three humans that piloted three giant machines, each with different abilities.
I don’t think they joined together to form a bigger bot, they were individuals.
I vaguely remember details, but one thing I do remember is that one of the pilots -- the blue one, I believe -- would say "aero speed" to activate his machine's ability, which was super speed. The other machines had their own respective sayings, abilities and colors.
From what I have researched so far, it's not:

Centurions
Robotech
Exosquad


If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are an excellent chance to [edit] your question, e.g. "I know that it can't be Lion Busters because two of the pilots were Russian and Ukrainian, often squabbling over 'how Communism ended' and their enemies piloted biological monstrosities made out of festering pus, not shiny robots in the shape of giant meter maids."

What colour were the individual machines, where they red, blue and yellow?

I wonder if you might be remembering Force Five: Starvengers, an English dub of Getter Robo G.


Like its predecessor, Getter Robo G is composed of three jet-like vehicles piloted by one of the three pilots. Dragon is the red jet, controlled by the pilot of Getter Dragon. Liger, the blue jet, is used by Getter Liger's pilot. Getter Poseidon's operator uses Poseidon, the yellow machine. All three are armed with missiles but are generally very weak and never used in combat unless absolutely necessary. They also appear when the pilots use the Open Get (Break Formation in the English version) verbal command to break up the current form, so that they can change into another, or so they can dodge an enemy's attack.

Getter Liger, the blue robot, was named Star Arrow in Starvengers, and was indeed known for its super speed. I have not made any confirmation that the phrase "Arrow Speed" was used, but this review does note that they do shout the names of their attacks when firing them off.

During these robot battles, every one of the pilots yells at the top of their lungs what weapon they are currently using.  If Star Dragon wants to throw his, admittedly awesome, Hatchet Boomerang, then Hummer yells, “Hatch-et Boom-erang!” right before the robot throws it.  The same with Star Arrow and even the evil robots do it.  Before Pandokogan fires his horn death ray he yells, “Kogan Horn!”  I guess the robots are voice activated.  Or, more appropriately, SCREAMING activated.

Arrow Formation, Arrow Go, Arrow Kick, Arrow Missile, and Arrow Drill do show up as phrases.
Star Arrow attacks



Opening and Closing Credits of Starvengers




And acknowledging that Bob mentioned Force Five first in their answer, but I felt like it was too big of a change (and enough effort on my part) to just edit their answer to add details.

I think the characters were called "Shogun Warriors". I don’t remember a TV show but I do remember having toys of all three robots. They were from the ‘70s and made by Mattel. They don’t join up together, but each has a special weapon.
There was a ‘90s cartoon called “Force Five” that took excerpts of five different Japanese shows, some of which featured the robots that the Shogun warriors were based on.

Thank you for the pointer on Force Five. It does look like this might be a good match.
